# Deriving formula of series and then finding value at a limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So the question follows:

> You post an update to social media that begins to garner attention. Within the first minute, you gain 1 new follower, in the second minute you gain another 2, in the third you gain another 4, in the fourth another 8, and so on.
>
> (a) Assuming that the pattern continues, use the formula for a geometric
>   sum to find a simple expression for your total number of new followers
>   Fk at the end of к minutes.
>
> (b) The population of the world is approximately 7.4 billion. How many
>   minutes will it take before the whole planet is following your success in
>   calculus?

So essentially, I interpreted this as a series with these values:
1, 3, 7, 15...

So my

a (first term)  = 1

r (multiplier)= an - an-1

Where n and n-1 are subscripts.

How would I put this into the geometric series formula
(a)/(1-r)

Comment: You're using the wrong formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F_k=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{i}=\frac{1-2^{k}}{1-2}=2^k-1$ and evaluate the inequality.
$F_k \geq 7400000000$ if $2^k-1 \geq 7.4 \times 10^9$ if $2^k \geq 7.4\times10^9-1$ if $k \geq \frac{ln(7.4\times10^9-1)}{ln(2)}$

Comment: Is there a reason "7.4" occurs twice in the first term following the if? "7.4 x 7.4"

Comment: My mistake sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Realize that the $nth$ term is just $2^n-1$.